# Eclipse Indigo Outline (PHP Mode, Subclipse) is flickering with large classes

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, outline

my Eclipse Indigo Outline is flickering when i click around 
the code of large php classes.
I think it has something to do with subclipse because after the flickering ends the revision number & date is displayed.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem ?

My eclipse looks like this:

```
  Android DDMS  18.0.0.v201203301601-306762

  Android Development Tools 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762

  Android Hierarchy Viewer  18.0.0.v201203301601-306762

  Android Traceview 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762

  CollabNet Merge Client    3.0.8

  Eclipse SDK   3.7.1.M20110909-1335

  PHP Development Tools (PDT) SDK Feature 3.0.0.v201201110400-77-184_2BEICRgM_fMVcz0M4Va9O

  Subclipse (Required)  1.8.9

  Subclipse Integration for Mylyn 3.x (Optional)    3.0.0

  Subversion Client Adapter (Required)  1.8.2

  Subversion JavaHL Native Library Adapter  1.7.4.1

  Subversion Revision Graph 1.1.1
```

Thank you,

Lucian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update to "***Eclipse SDK Version: 3.7.2 Build id: M20120208-0800***"
solved my problem ! The outline doesnt blink anymore.

Lucian

Comment: It seems that i also forgot to switch from JAVA to PHP Mode while editing large PHP classes, which could also have caused the blinking...